# Setting up a VM hostname: undefined method `hostname'

Tags: vagrant

I'm trying to set host name for VM. Here my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.box = "opensuse-12.3-32"
  config.vm.define :web do |web_config|
    web_config.vm.hostname "web.my.net"
    web_config.vm.forward_port 80, 7080
    web_config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
      puppet.manifests_path = "puppet"
      puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
      puppet.manifest_file  = "base.pp"
    end
  end
end
```

But it leads to the following error:

```
/home/coder/vagrant/opensuse/Vagrantfile:40:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `hostname' for #<VagrantPlugins::Kernel_V1::VMConfig:0x00000002748fb8> (NoMethodError)
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.1/lib/vagrant/config/v1/loader.rb:37:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.1/lib/vagrant/config/v1/loader.rb:37:in `load'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:104:in `block (2 levels) in load'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:98:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:98:in `block in load'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:95:in `each'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.1/lib/vagrant/config/loader.rb:95:in `load'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:335:in `machine'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.1/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:134:in `block in with_target_vms'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.1/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:167:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.1/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:167:in `block in with_target_vms'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.1/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:166:in `map'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.1/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:166:in `with_target_vms'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.1/plugins/commands/status/command.rb:16:in `execute'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.1/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:38:in `execute'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.1/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:484:in `cli'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.3.1/bin/vagrant:96:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/bin/vagrant:23:in `load'
    from /opt/vagrant/bin/../embedded/gems/bin/vagrant:23:in `<main>'
```

I'm using Vagrant 1.3.1 under Ubuntu 12.10. (64 bit) and OpenSuSe 12.3 (32 bit) as VM.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try:

> web_config.vm.hostname = "web.my.net"

Comment: Yes, it's helped. But in my case I used `host_name` instead of `hostname`.

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but I'm using a windows box, and it won't let me use a '.' or '_' in my hostname. I don't know if this is normal behavior or not because all of the documentation and notes on the issue i've seen, all use a period. Someone may find this as useful knowledge, or could point out where i'm mistaken. I'm using the [opentable/win-2012r2-standard-amd64-nocm](https://vagrantcloud.com/opentable/boxes/win-2012r2-standard-amd64-nocm) box

Answer (score 37):

What you have is a mismatch between your code and the version of the Vagrant API you are using.

- For Vagrant API v1 use `config.vm.host_name`.
- For Vagrant API v2 use `config.vm.hostname`.

Comment: Thanks for the definitive answer, strange anomaly - I'm using the v2 API with `host_name` and it works fine. Changed it to `hostname` and it still works fine. I guess they have a bit of backwards compatibility code in there.

Comment: That must have happened recently! When I wrote this answer the v2 API would choke `host_name`. Thanks for the additional information.

Answer (score 14):

As per issue [#1974](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/1974), setting hostname you should be using => `config.vm.hostname = "web.my.net"`

So the block should look like

```rb
  config.vm.define :web do |web_config|
    web_config.vm.hostname = "web.my.net"
    web_config.vm.forward_port 80, 7080
    web_config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
      puppet.manifests_path = "puppet"
      puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
      puppet.manifest_file  = "base.pp"
    end
  end
```

You can even generate some random hostname by using code below

```rb
config.vm.hostname = "devops#{rand(01..99)}.vagrant.vm}"
```

Answer (score 10):

edit `Vagrantfile`:

```
config.vm.hostname = "WhateverHostNameYouWant"
```

Eg:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"
  config.vm.hostname = "vhost1.local"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
end
```